# ledcWriteTone leaking to other pin?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, led, frequency, nodemcu

I've recently written a program that involves two blinking LEDs. I have these LEDs wired straight from the pins into GND. One is set to blink on and off on one second intervals, and the other is fed a signal via the ledcWriteTone function built into the ESP.

The behavior I am seeing is that whenever I have my ledcWriteTone controlled LED active and flashing, the same flashing also is occurring on my 1 second blink LED whenever it is on it's on cycle.

I do not suspect any kind of electrical connection causing signal leakage. Measuring between pins with the MCU depowered I get an expected high resistance of about 16 MOhms. I don't believe I am getting variables switched around and doubled up on in my code either. Oddly enough, I only seem to have this behavior for led channels 8 and 9. Unfortunately I already have some PCBs made that are using channels 1-7 so going back isn't really an option for me. Going higher seems to have the same issues. I was under the impression NodeMCU32S' have 16 led channels, so I didn't suspect I would run the risk of running out.

[image]

**Hardware:**

NodeMCU-32S

2 5mm Green LEDs

**Code:**

```
#define LED1 19
#define LED2 23

long currentMillis;
long timeSinceRead;
int ledFreq;
int previousledFreq;
long timeSinceBlink;
int blinkActive;


void setup() {
ledcSetup(8, 1000, 8);
ledcSetup(9, 1000, 8);

ledcAttachPin(LED1, 8);
ledcAttachPin(LED2, 9);
ledcWrite(8,255);
ledcWrite(9,255);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(millis()-timeSinceRead > 100){
    ledFreq = map(analogRead(POT), 0, 4096, 0, 90);
    if(ledFreq < 1){
      ledFreq = 0;
    }

    if(ledFreq != previousledFreq){
      ledcWriteTone(9, ledFreq);
      previousledFreq = ledFreq;
    }
  timeSinceRead = millis();
  }

  if(millis() - timeSinceBlink > 1000 && blinkActive == 0){
    ledcWrite(8, 255);
    timeSinceBlink = millis();
    blinkActive = 1;
  }
  if(millis() - timeSinceBlink > 1000 && blinkActive == 1){
    ledcWrite(8, 0);
    timeSinceBlink = millis();
    blinkActive = 0;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 3/18/2023:**
I modified this program to run through a series of cycles adjusting the assigned channel of the LEDs and took the following data. Seems that when the channel is an odd number, it's pattern is copied to the channel below it, and when even, copied to the channel in front of it. Below is an image of that data.

[image]

Green indicates no copied channel information.
Red indicates copied information.
Black are combinations that would overlap the channels, so they are skipped.

If anyone could shed some light on this, I'd really appreciate it! My code is below.

```
#define POT 34
#define LED1 19
#define LED2 23

long currentMillis;
long timeSinceRead;
long timeSinceRead2;
int ledFreq;
int previousledFreq;
long timeSinceBlink;
int blinkActive;
int slowBlinkChan = 0;
int fastBlinkChan = 1;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("");
ledcSetup(slowBlinkChan, 2000, 8);
ledcSetup(fastBlinkChan, 2000, 8);

ledcAttachPin(LED1, slowBlinkChan);
ledcAttachPin(LED2, fastBlinkChan);
ledcWriteTone(fastBlinkChan, 20);
Serial.print("slowBlinkChan on Channel: ");
Serial.println(slowBlinkChan);
Serial.print("fastBlinkChan on Channel: ");
Serial.println(fastBlinkChan);
Serial.println("BEGIN");
}

void loop() {
  if(millis() - timeSinceRead2 > 10000){ //Every 6 seconds ( 6 flashes on slow LED), increment channel of slow LED by one.
    timeSinceRead2 = millis();      
    fastBlinkChan = fastBlinkChan+1;
    Serial.println("fastblink increment");
    if(fastBlinkChan == slowBlinkChan){
      Serial.println("overlap prevention");
      fastBlinkChan = fastBlinkChan + 1;  //channel overlap prevention
    }
    if(fastBlinkChan > 15){          //Every cycle of the slow LED going through its 16 cycles (channels), increment fastblink channel by 1 until reaching 16. Upon reaching that, perform a "double reset" where the channels are reset back to their beginning values.
      Serial.println("STANDARD RESET");
      fastBlinkChan = 0;
      slowBlinkChan = slowBlinkChan + 1;
      if(slowBlinkChan > 15){
        slowBlinkChan = 1;
        Serial.println("DOUBLE RESET");
      }
    }
    Serial.print("slowBlinkChan on Channel: ");
    Serial.println(slowBlinkChan);
    Serial.print("fastBlinkChan on Channel: ");
    Serial.println(fastBlinkChan);
    Serial.println(" ");
    ledcSetup(slowBlinkChan, 2000, 8);
    ledcSetup(fastBlinkChan, 2000, 8);
    ledcAttachPin(LED1, slowBlinkChan);
    ledcAttachPin(LED2, fastBlinkChan);
    ledcWriteTone(fastBlinkChan, 20);
    
  }

  if(millis() - timeSinceBlink > 1000 && blinkActive == 0){
    ledcWrite(slowBlinkChan, 255);
    timeSinceBlink = millis();
    blinkActive = 1;
  }
  if(millis() - timeSinceBlink > 1000 && blinkActive == 1){
    ledcWrite(slowBlinkChan, 0);
    timeSinceBlink = millis();
    blinkActive = 0;
  }
}
```